# Connection String related error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using Windows authentication for SQL Server in my project and the error I receive while saving the data is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My connection string is:

```
Server=LOKESH; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Comment: is it sql express? if yes then try `server=lokesh\sqlexpress`

Comment: If the server is on another machine make sure port 1433 is open on yours and its firewall

Comment: 1) Make sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  2) If a named instance, add a backslash and instance name after the connection string.  3) Make sure the SQL Server service is running and the port it is listening on (1433 for default instance, dynamic for named instance) is allowed through firewall.